# How to run a batch job using a git repository containing a Dockerfile and a python script on AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I prepared a repository with a python script which I run in a docker container. The Dockerfile is also in the repository.

I tried ECS + Batch jobs, but it seems overcomplicated for such a task.

I would like to use an AWS service that clones this repository, builds the container and runs the script. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can start an EC2 instance that will run this script (assuming you use Amazon Linux or Centos AMI) at startup, using [User Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

yum update -y
yum install -y docker git

service docker start

git clone https://github.com/yourcompany/yourproject myproject
cd myproject

docker build -t my-docker-image .
docker run my-docker-image
```

Comment: That sounds like a good approach. So I could start as many instances as needed and parametrize using the launch script. The downside is that each instance would have to build it's own container.

Comment: What you could do to avoid building the Docker image is pull it from AWS ECR, Docker Hub or Quay.io. If you need to launch multiple instances, you should use autoscaling groups.